# android studio xml format

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-studio

I'm working on an android application but I have some problem with my xml.
I use Android Studio and when I put something like a Button in my visual xml file, and I lock is position. I use the background image as a reference for the button position but on my tablet everything goes wrong. My button goes to another position.
I have already setted the device on Android Studio.
How can I resolve?
do you need some code?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right click in Button then make it be constrain by   choose center > center horizontally or center vertically. Make sure no warning symbol show again.